# UITableViewCellでchildViewControllersを参照したい

Tags: ios

Storybordで、UIViewControllerにContainerViewを配置した時、UIViewController#childViewControllersでembedに指定した子ViewControllerが参照できます。

TableCellにContainerViewを配置した時は、UITableViewCellからどのように参照すればよいでしょうか。

やりたいことは、PrototypeCellにContainerViewを配置し、TableViewDataSouce#tableview:cellForRowA‌​tInexPathメソッドでChildViewのコンポーネントに値を設定するということです。

Comment: `UITableViewController`に`ContainerView`を配置する時は、`Static Cells`になるので、「`UITableViewCell`から`ChildViewControllers`を参照する」という状況が見えないです。もう少し背景を記述すると良い気がします。

Comment: DynamicCellでContinerViewは利用できないということでしょうか。
やりたいことは、PrototypeCellにContainerViewを配置し、TableViewDataSouce#tableview:cellForRowAtInexPathメソッドでChildViewのコンポーネントに値を設定するということです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

実験してみましたが、
Illegal Configuration
 Container Views cannot be placed in elements that are repeated at runtime.

とbuild errorになります。
環境:Xcode 6.4
手順: TableViewCellの中のContentViewの中に、ContainerViewを貼り付け。テーブルは、dynamic.

IBは、操作を許しますが、ビルドエラーになります。

だから、できないのでは。完全staticのtableなら許してくれるかも知れませんが。